# Est-ce qu'un puits vers le haut peut être profond?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Imaginons que nous sommes dans une grotte. Au-dessus de nous se trouve une ouverture qui s'ouvre sur un tunnel vertical duquel on parvient avec peine à voir l'extrémité. Peut-on dire que ce trou vertical est profond? 
Ça semble étrange étant donné qu'on associe le mot "profond" à ce qui est vers le bas. Ai-je tort?

Answer (score 9):

Tout d'abord le mot « profond »,  n'est pas forcément associé à la direction verticale.
Il est aussi facilement associé à la direction horizontale, on parle d'une grotte profonde quand celle-ci s'étend horizontalement et que le fond est très éloigné de l'entrée de la grotte sans pour autant qu'elle s'enfonce verticalement.
De même une forêt profonde est une forêt dense dont le centre est éloigné du bord.

Dans ton exemple nous sommes bien dans la direction verticale. Et tout est une question de point de vue. Pour celui qui se trouve à l'autre extrémité du tunnel, le tunnel est effectivement profond. Cependant certains préféreront ne pas employer « profond » s'ils se trouvent au fond et dire que le tunnel est « haut ».

- Je suis tombé au fond du puits et n'ai pas pu remonter à la surface parce qu'il était trop haut.

Answer (score 8):

Puisqu'on fait manifestement de la spéléo, autant utiliser le vocabulaire usuel dans ce monde :

En spéléologie un *tunnel vertical* qui s'ouvre au *dessus de nous* s'appelle :

Une **cheminée**.

J'ai effectivement pu parfois lire *puits remontant*. c'est plus rare tant... dans les rapports, sur les cartes... moins il y a de lettres à écrire et... mieux c'est.

Et donc, là où tu te trouves à l'instant c'est : *le pied de la cheminée.* (c'est encore à dire... pas le *fond*)

Si, dans l'usage courant, les mots *profond* *profondeur* peuvent s'appliquer à divers axes de l'espace dans un sens d'éloignement par rapport à une ouverture, restreint au domaine de la spéléo, je n'ai jamais lu ces mots employés autrement que pour se référer à l'**axe vertical orienté vers le bas**. (*1) (En particulier sur les cartes sur lesquelles les niveaux de profondeur sont scrupuleusement relevés)

Que dire alors relativement à une cheminée ? (qui n'a donc pas de fond mais un pied) Eh bien tout simplement qu'elle est **haute** et parler de sa **hauteur**.

---

<sup>(*1) On cote d'ailleurs les *profondeurs* avec des nombres positifs. Quand l'axe est orienté vers le haut, on ne parle plus de profondeur, on parle d'altitude, de cote ou de niveau et les niveaux en-dessous de la référence (souvent l'entrée) étant alors cotés avec des nombres négatifs. À la Rasse, par exemple, on est descendu à la cote de -690 mètres ou encore... à 690 m de profondeur.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Profond ne se rapporte pas forcément à ce qui est vers le bas. Par exemple, lorsque l'on parle des dimensions d'un meuble, la profondeur est la mesure de la distance entre l'avant et l'arrière de ce meuble.

Je dirais donc que qualifier de profonde une longue ouverture, même vers le haut, est correct.

A noter en revanche qu'un puits est toujours vers le bas, un "puits vers le haut" n'est pas correct.

Comment: Un puits vers le haut n'a rien de pas correct. On parle par exemple de « puits de lumière »

Comment: Un puits de lumière va bien vers le bas, puisque la lumière vient du ciel.

Comment: Je suis bien d'accord pour dire que *pro**fond*** peut s'appliquer à beaucoup de choses mais à la condition (à mon opinion nécessaire) que ce quelque chose ait... : un **fond** (quelle que soit la signification qu'on lui donne.) Dans cette optique, il me semble un peu paradoxal de considérer qu'une *ouverture* puisse avoir un fond.

Comment: Prenons un meuble sans fond, tel un meuble pour ranger des paniers dans le style d'Ikea. Je peux toujours mesurer sa profondeur. Un arbre a des racines profondes, une forêt peut être profonde, le noir, la nuit, le sommeil. Rien de tout cela n'a de fond.

Comment: @ThomasMartin À ce compte là si on se place à son sommet, un puits vers le haut est vers le bas, ça n'a donc pas grand sens de dire que ce n'est pas correct

Comment: @ThomasMartin : Tu marques le point! (Même si certains de tes exemples pourraient être considérés comme des extensions de sens.)

Comment: @Evpok un puits est une construction humaine dont la _fonction_ est de descendre. D'ailleurs on ne monte pas dans un puits, on remonte, après y avoir descendu. Cette nuance montre que la fonction est de descendre. Peu importe donc d'où on se place. De la même façon une tour reste une tour, que l'on soit monté sur le toit ou redescendu. Et on ne dit pas "une tour vers le bas" quand on est au sommet de celle-ci. Je conviens que le mot puits a une signification plus large aujourd'hui, comme un puits de connaissance, mais je persiste à dire que "puits vers le haut" est au mieux maladroit.